# PHP - Correct syntax for multiple reference/urlencode

Tags: php

i want multiple urlencode in the path. i do not know how to do it. I am quite new in php so please help. thank you.

in search_form.php

```
<td>
    <a 
      href="items.php?filepath='.urlencode($path).'?name='.urlencode($name)'?type='.urlencode($type)'"
      onClick="MM_openBrWindow(\'items.php?filepath='.urlencode($path). '\',\'google\',\'width=650,height=500\'); return false;">
        <img src="Folder-Blank-icon.png">
    </a>
</td>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "multiple" urlencode?

Comment: this. items.php?filepath='.urlencode($path).'?name='.urlencode($name)'?type='.urlencode($type)'"

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Are you seeing an error?

Comment: You're typically only supposed to put a `?` before the first get param; the rest should have `&` before them. Otherwise they won't come through as `$_GET` arguments on the PHP side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Forget `urlencode`. It's easier to do it like this:

```
$url = 'items.php?'.http_build_query(array('filepath'=>$path, 'name'=>$name, 'type'=>$type))
```

This will add the `&` inbetween each, and it's cleaner and simpler.

Answer (score -1):

You're missing the concatenation operator, `.`, in a couple of places (after `$name` and `$type`), and you're not combining the different parameters in the URL correctly:

```
echo '<a href="items.php?filepath='.urlencode($path).'&name='.urlencode($name).'&type='.urlencode($type).'"
onClick="MM_openBrWindow(\'items.php?filepath='.urlencode($path). '\',\'google\',\'width=650,height=500\'); return false;">
<img src="Folder-Blank-icon.png">
</a>';
```